# If statement preventing submit button to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

My submit button won't work because of the first `if` statement. If I remove the block, the button works. The statement seems to break the view. Why?

```
<% if params[:action] == "edit" %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form_tag :action => "edit" do %>
        <%= select_tag :vehicle_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicles, :id, :model, params[:id].to_i), :onchange => "this.form.submit()" %> 
      <% end -%>
      <%= link_to 'Nouvelle voiture', new_vehicle_path %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Modèle" %>
    <%= f.text_field :model, required: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Immatriculation" %>
    <%= f.text_field :license_plate, required: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Complément" %>
    <%= f.text_field :complement, required: true%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Puissance CV" %>
    <%= f.number_field :horse_power, required: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Indemnité KM" %>
    <%= f.number_field :km_compensation, required: true%>
  </div>

  <% if params[:action] == "edit" %>
    <%= link_to 'Détruire', @vehicle, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Êtes-vous sûr ? Les trajets associés seront aussi détruits.' } %>
    <h1>Trajets</h1>

    <div>
      <span>Clients</span>
      <span>Kms aller/retour</span>
    </div> 

    <%= f.fields_for :trip_distances do |builder| %>   
        <div class="field">
          <%= builder.text_field :id_contract %>
          <%= builder.number_field :length %>
        </div>
    <% end -%>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Sauvegarder' %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I didn't need the `form_tag`:

```
  <%= form_tag :action => "edit" do %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put `if` statement you don't have form in which your submit button resides. Without `if` statement your form is in the view, and you can submit to it.

Comment: Yes, but is there a workaround that I could use so that the if statement could still be at the same position? I need them.

Comment: What do you need when `if` statement is false? Do you need some other form ?

Comment: In both cases (true and false), the rest of the code has to be displayed.This is the only form I use.

Comment: It seems to be in fact the form_tag that's breaking the view, not the if statement.